# transaction not showing in sandbox

Tags: paypal

The test sale is being processed by HikaShop, going completely through the PayPal process and a confirmed payment email is being sent to the owner of the test store but the transaction is not showing in the owner's sandbox.
This is my first attempt at setting up an online store using PayPal and I don't know what to do next.
Help appreciated.

Edit: I added the buyer to the seller's sandbox accounts. I can now see the email confirmation to the buyer on the sandbox notifications but I still can't see any transactions.
Help appreciated

Comment: Double-check that your sandbox test appID is saved correctly in your webapp and you are using the right API endpoints for all requests.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. I hadn't added the buyer to the owner's sandbox.

Comment: Not solved :(   Please see edit above.